# Error handling Selenium if element doesn't exist

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to write and if/else statement if my find_element_by_xpath returns a valid element or not an

```
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='price']").text
location = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='listing__address']").text

if (SOMETHINGGOESHEREIFELEMENTEXISTS)
    print(price, location)
    driver.quit()
else:
    print("QUITING!")
    driver.quit()
```

In both cases I want to do a driver.quit.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html), `find_element_by_xpath()` raises a `NoSuchElementException` exception when it fails. Then the following should work:

```py
try:
    price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='price']").text
    location = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='listing__address']").text
    print(price, location)
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("QUITTING!")
driver.quit()
```